# Unable to read an SMS from Sim900a

Tags: sms, embedded

I have interface `PIC16f877A` with `sim900a` directly. I can send SMS but in case of **Receving/Reading** an SMS from `sim900a` I am failing.

I am unable to find the error, has anyone had a similar experience?

Comment: Yes - every time I interface to an external device.  We cannot debug hardware and software by blog.  What have you found out so far from your own debugging?

Comment: Thanx martin for reply,

Comment: i have made the circuit and programing in such a way that if my PIc16f877a receive any sms from sim900a it will print it on lcd 16x2.

Comment: sry for multiple thread  ...... i cant read sms from sim900a even my code is accurate because i have checked it with hyperterminal...so what another error cane be there? why my PIC unable to read sms from sim900a

Answer (score 0):

Are the indicators for receiving an SMS message set correctly in the modem?
Ensure:

AT+CNMI=1,1,0,0,0